# Explicit formula for $x(0)=0, x(n+1) = x(n)^2 +1$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

If $f(x) = \sqrt{x-1}$ and we  compose $f(x)$ $k$ times, then a recursive formula for its zero, $x(k)$, is given by the recursive formula relation 
$x(0)=0, x(n+1) = x(n)^2 + 1$.

This is nice, but how might we find an explicit formula for $x(k)$?

Comment: The formula might be linked to a fibonacci sequence. I propose that you study some identities of the famous Fibonacci sequence.

Comment: Not sure if there is one.. https://oeis.org/search?q=0%2C1%2C2%2C5%2C26%2C677&language=german&go=Suche

Comment: There's [this](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Binet%27s_Formula).

Comment: Conjecture: Let $x(n)$ be expressed as $P(x(n-k)) $ and let $\alpha_{k,i}$ be the $i^{th}$ non-zero coefficient in $P(x(n-k))$. Then $\alpha_{k,1} = 1, \alpha_{k,2} = 2^{k-1}, \alpha_{k,3} = {2^{k-1}+1\choose 2} - 2^{k-2}$

Comment: Take a look at http://oeis.org/A003095